# About Linear Regression

Tags: economics, least-squares

Let the regression model of $y_i$ over $x_i$, $i=1,2...,N$$$y_i=\beta x_i+u_i$$, then $$\beta=\frac{\sum y_ix_i }{\sum x_i^2}=\frac{\sum y_i }{N}=\bar{y}$$

The problem is that I can't see how to obtain the equality.

Comment: The assertion $\frac{\sum y_ix_i }{\sum x_i^2}=\frac{\sum y_i }{N}$ isn't true. Are there additional assumptions?

Comment: Nope, Im guessing that is a typo in my notes.

Comment: Yep, if that central equals sign were not there, you would have two true statements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $u_i, i=1,\ldots,N$ represent the errors. In a least squares method, the aim is to minimize the sum of the squared errors, that is, to find $\beta$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} u_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i - \beta x_i)^2$$
is minimal. To that end, compute the derivative of the RHS w.r.t $\beta$ and set this expression equal to zero. Solving for $\beta$ gives then the required value.

Comment: Yep. If I do that I have the first part of the equality, however, I can't see why is equal to the mean of $y$